# How can I shorten this sequence of numbers in my pipe component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm calculating an average for this I've created a custom pipe, but I can't display 1 figure then 2 figures separated by a dot? I don't understand where to use the slice() method.

example current result = 2.66666666666666 => expected output 2.66

thanks.

**Custom pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
name: 'average'
})
export class AveragePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: number[]): any {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + +b, 0) / items.length;
  }
}
```

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I don't understand how to use it in my case. I've tried several things but no.